# New-LocalUser and Add-LocalGroupMember are not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

While running the PowerShell script to add an account to local administrators group on remote Windows 2012 computer, I am getting the error

> New-LocalUser and Add-LocalGroupMember are not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding that the x86 version of PowerShell is unable to see the LocalAccounts module.

The solution is to run the x64 version of PowerShell (which is the one marked with neither x86 nor x64).