# how to install New-LocalUser and read the help file from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, administrator, microsoft-surface, control-panel

Looks to be a 64 bit OS but 32 bit powershell, if I'm reading this correctly:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20200329133946
Username: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\thufir
RunAs User: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\thufir
Configuration Name: 
Machine: DESKTOP-9AKB65V (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18362.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 7552
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.628
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.628
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.628
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\thufir\Documents\PowerShell_transcript.DESKTOP-9AKB65V.FybEZQNt.20200329133946.txt
PS C:\Users\thufir> [System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess
False
PS C:\Users\thufir> Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem | Select-Object OSArchitecture

OSArchitecture
--------------
64-bit


PS C:\Users\thufir> Stop-Transcript
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200329134006
**********************
```

---

original question:

On a Surface 3, after starting `PowerShell` as an administrator I'm not seeing help on creating a new local user:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Help New-LocalUser
Get-Help : Get-Help could not find New-LocalUser in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics type:
"Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Help New-LocalUser
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

see also:

https://winaero.com/blog/create-user-account-windows-10-powershell/

and

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

seems unlikely to apply, but I do see:

> Note
>
> The Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts module is not available in 32-bit PowerShell on a 64-bit system.

yet, see:

Note

The Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts module is not available in 32-bit PowerShell on a 64-bit system.

although I'd expect (hope) that anything running windows 10, as this surface 3, is running 64 bit...

[New-LocalUser and Add-LocalGroupMember are not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://superuser.com/q/1461846/55747)

Comment: What happens when you use `New-LocalUser`, get any errors? Did you run `Update-Help`?

Comment: Also, let us know the output of `$env:Processor_Architecture`

Comment: oof, @jfrmilner it comes back as `x86` which I take as 32 bit.  Can that be right?  It's a surface3 running windows 10.  I thought windows 10 was 64 bit only...   I've run update help many times.

Comment: Win10 is available in 32bit. So, tells us that you're using the 32bit version of PowerShell. Now let's check the OS, could you run `Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem | Select-Object OSArchitecture`

Comment: to determine if PoSh is running 32bit or 64bit, try this >>> `[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess` <<<

Comment: Looks to be 64 bit architecture, @Lee_Dailey which I added to the question.

Comment: looks to be 32 bit process @jfrmilner which is a bit odd, to my understanding.  If it's 64 bit architecture, why run PS in 32 bit??  Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @Thufir - the `SysWow` in the path means you are running the 32bit version of PoSh ... that is what that directory structure is about - 32bit on 64bit. whatever is starting your PoSh session is calling for that version - and the usual cause is the app that is calling PoSh is 32bit. this is notorious with Jenkins, for instance. you need to find out what is calling PoSh in 32bit mode.

Comment: okay, thanks.  I had no idea.  It's just a surface 3 tablet which I received a few years.

Comment: @Thufir - so ... how are you starting powershell? exactly what steps?

Comment: I wasd literally clicking the wrong button @Lee_Dailey

Comment: @Thufir - i have ~~neevr~~ never made any such error ... [*grin*]